# how to add more than 1 value to textFormFields?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am developing a flutter e-commerce app.

in the app, we have added a product screen to which the user can add products.

the difference between adding a product in my app and in a normal app is the user should be able to add product details in more than one language.

this is add_product_screen

[image]

each time the user tap (English, Kurdish, Arabic) buttons he/she would be able to add (Description, Used materials) in that language.

without removing other languages values of course, because I need to send it all together to the backend.

any idea??

Comment: Depends on the use-case, When language switch have the map value inside your class `like Map<String, Model>` whenever switch save the desciption, userMaterial into map use language as key. And same time when switch check whether map contains value if contains show to ui.

Comment: did that help you or need some snippet i can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

You can use different object of ModelClass for each language, or you can create a List of String and remember the index accordingly,
for example
List languages = [];

and then assign values according to index, for English index 0, for Arabic index 2 and so on.